# Crystal Reports SQL and Fluke MetTrack

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a database running Fluke MetTrack v8.1, this runs on a Sybase database and connects over ODBC. 
I would like to be able to write SQL code within the reports in order for them to run a little bit faster.  But all of the examples I've seen are written as {Inventory.I4201} but I haven't been able to get any SQL to run an example of this would be:

```
SELECT "Inventory"."I4201", "Inventory"."I4240"
FROM   "mt"."Inventory" "Inventory"
WHERE  "Inventory"."I4240"='MT' AND "Inventory"."I4201"='sample-11'
```

And that's the SQL code that is generated by Crystal Reports and that gives me the error:

```
  Error in compiling SQL Expression:
  Database Connector Error: '42000:[Sybase][ODBC Driver]
  [SQL Anywhere]Syntax error near 'SELECT' on line 1 
  [Database Vendor Code:-131]'.
```

I know when I write SQL code in the database I write it like this:

```
Select i.i4201
from mt.inventory "i"
where i.i4240='mt' and i.i4201='sample-11'
```

(and when I use it in crystal it gives the same error)

Any help with getting me on the right path would be appreciated.

EDIT: this happens even without an alias given to the table

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with SQL I have never wrapped an alias in double quotes. I would suggest adding the ODBC Command like this:

```
SELECT I.I4201
FROM mt.inventory I
WHERE I.I4240 = "mt" AND I.I4201 = "sample-11"
```